# change resource verbs laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.5

In laravel I've route like this:

```
Route::resource('calificaciones', 'CatCalificacionesController'); //in spanish
```

Edit and create routes are this:

```
calificaciones/{id}/edit
calificaciones/create
```

I need to translate **"edit"** to **"editar"** and **"create"** to **"crear"** in laravel 5.5 this is posible using:

```
Route::resourceVerbs([
    'create' => 'crear',
    'edit' => 'editar',
]);
```

in the **AppServiceProvider**

Is there any way to do it this in laravel 5.2 or I need to declare my routes one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2 it's hard-coded so you cannot use such method. You need to create routes manually.

You can see implementation of create for example:

```
protected function addResourceCreate($name, $base, $controller, $options)
{
    $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name).'/create';
    $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'create', $options);
    return $this->router->get($uri, $action);
}
```

as you see `/create` here is hard-coded so it cannot be easily replaced.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I had hope there was a way. so i need to declare all my routes manually.

Comment: Or you can upgrade to latest release :)